# recibir todos los datos de un socket telnet con asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

Estoy haciendo pruebas de comunicación con una ccu por telnet, conecto con ella, recibo el promp pero nada mas, parece no recivir los comandos y por tanto, no responder

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
# encoding: utf-8
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import asyncio

async def tcp_echo_client(message):
    writer = None
    try:
        error = 'No se ha podido establecer una conexión'
        reader, writer = await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.open_connection(
            IP, PUERTO), timeout=2)
        print(f'Send: {message!r}')
        error = f'No ha sido posible enviar el mensaje'
        writer.write(message.encode())
        error = f'No se ha recibido respuesta'
        data = await asyncio.wait_for(reader.read(1024), timeout=2)
        print(f'Recibido: {data!r}')
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print('Se ha superado el tiempo de espera')
        print(error)
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        print('La máquina remota ha rechazado la conexión')
    print('Close the connection')
    if writer:
        writer.close()
        await writer.wait_closed()
asyncio.run(tcp_echo_client('help'))
```

He probado otros comandos, cambiar el tamaño del buffer, todo sin resultado, la verdad, no sé que puede estar pasando.

También he probado con readline y con readuntil, de nuevo sin resultados.

He probado a incluir retorno de carro \n y \r juntos y por separado

Conectando por telnet desde la consola funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de varias horas peleándome con diferentes formas de recoger los datos he logrado dar con la solución:

```
# encoding: utf-8
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import asyncio

async def tcp_echo_client(message, code='iso-8859-1', cr=False):
writer = None
if isinstance(message, bytes):
    message = message.decode()
if cr:
    message = f"{message}\r\n"
try:
    error = 'No se ha podido establecer una conexión'
    reader, writer = await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.open_connection(
        IP, PUERTO), timeout=2)
    print(f'Send: {message!r}')
    error = f'No ha sido posible enviar el mensaje'
    writer.write(message.encode(code))
    error = f'No se ha recibido respuesta'
    received = ''
    lines = list()
    buffer = None
    while True:
        # Los datos de la CCU van codificados como 'iso-8859-1'
        data = await asyncio.wait_for(reader.readline(), timeout=.5)
        # print(f'Recibido: {data!r}')
        line = data.decode(code)
        received = f"{received}{line}"
        if not data:
            break
        else:
            lines.append(line)

except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    if received != '':
        buffer = received
        # print('Datos recibidos', received)
    else:
        print('Se ha superado el tiempo de espera')
        print(error)
except ConnectionRefusedError:
    print('La máquina remota ha rechazado la conexión')
if buffer:
    print(f'Recividas {len(lines)} lineas')
print('Cerrando la conexion')
if writer:
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()
return lines, buffer
```

Como se puede observar hay varios cambios:

Primero he agregado \r\n a los mensajes para simular el enter

Segundo he cambiado el

```
data = await asyncio.wait_for(reader.read(1024), timeout=2)
```

por un bucle que va recuperando las lineas recividas hasta que no queda ninguna

```
while True:
    # Los datos de la CCU van codificados como 'iso-8859-1'
    data = await asyncio.wait_for(reader.readline(), timeout=.5)
    # print(f'Recibido: {data!r}')
    line = data.decode(code)
    received = f"{received}{line}"
    if not data:
        break
    else:
        lines.append(line)
```

Todavía me queda lidiar con que decode me convierte \r\n en \r\n pero eso, es otro problema aparte.

Espero que la solución ayude a alguien